# ¿Cómo aplicar una función a distintas listas y me retorne un mensaje como resultado en Python?

Tags: python, lista, números-primos

Estoy iniciando en Python y me encuentro con el siguiente problema de aplicación de funciones en listas.

Debo definir una función que me permita identificar si un número de una lista determinada es primo o no. La función que hice para identificar si un número es primo es la siguiente:

```
def encontrar_primo(n):
  for i in range(2,n):
    if (n%i) == 0:
      return 'No es prim'
  return 'Es primo'
```

EDIT: La función anterior está hecha para recibir un número y no una lista, el problema es que no sé como hacer una función que espere una lista, es parte de mis dudas ahora que estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python.

Tengo 5 listas en donde debo aplicar la función anterior a cada elemento.

```
list1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
list2 = [1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 15]
list3 = [37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59]
list4 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 19, 39]
list5 = [3, 5, 7, 13]
```

Para cada lista, se debe aplicar la función y se debe retornar un mensaje con los siguientes criterios:

1. Si en la lista **TODOS son primos**, debe aparecer el mensaje *Todos son primos*.
2. Si en la lista  **1 o más números** son **no primos**, debe aparecer el mensaje *Alguno no es primo*.

Tomando en cuenta las listas anteriores, el resultado debería ser el siguiente:

```
list1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10] # Alguno no es primo
list2 = [1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 15] #  Alguno no es primo
list3 = [37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59] # Todos son primos
list4 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 19, 39] #  Alguno no es primo
list5 = [3, 5, 7, 13] # Todos son primos
```

He intentado aplicar mi función a las listas mediante la función `.map` de la siguiente forma:

```
resultado1 = list(map(encontrar_primo,list1))
print(resultado1)
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
['Es primo', 'Es primo', 'No es primo', 'Es primo', 'No es primo']
```

Es aquí donde no sé como continuar para que mi función itere en las 5 listas y me regrese 1 solo resultado y no lo haga por cada elemento en la lista. ¿Tienen alguna sugerencia?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: La funcion publicada espera un numero, no una lista. Pasarle una lista deberia de producir un error. Podrias agregar un código que produzca el comportamiento no deseado para que te podamos ayudar por favor?

Comment: Ese es otro de mis problema ya que me basé de `map` para aplicar la función sobre una lista... No sé como hacer que la función espere una lista y no un número específico. Como mencionaba, soy muy nuevo en Python y no sabría como responderte.

Comment: Entiendo eso. Pero de por si es raro que en tu pregunta indiques que te da un resultado asi, cuando el código deberia de dar un error ante la primera lista, ya que range no acepta listas. Para ayudarte mas facilmente, deberia de poder ejecutar el código en mi computadora y darme lo mismo que vos. Lo que te digo es un tema de comunicacion mas que de programacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar a implementarlo de esta forma:

```
list1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10] # Alguno no es primo
list2 = [1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 15] #  Alguno no es primo
list3 = [37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59] # Todos son primos
list4 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 19, 39] #  Alguno no es primo
list5 = [3, 5, 7, 13] # Todos son primos


def primo(n: list):

    cont = 0
    for num in n:

        for i in range(2,num):

            if num%i == 0:
                cont += 1
    
    if cont > 0:
        print('Alguno no es primo')
    else:
        print('Todos son primos')



primo(list1)
primo(list2)
primo(list3)
primo(list4)
primo(list5)
```

Salida:

```
Alguno no es primo
Alguno no es primo
Todos son primos
Alguno no es primo
Todos son primos
```

El contador aumenta si detecta que algún número de la lista no es primo, después se comprueba si el contador es mayor de 0 para ofrecer un único resultado.

A la función se le pasa la lista que quieras, el primer bucle es para recorrer cada valor de la lista y el segundo es la función que comprueba si dicho número es primo.

Puedes hacerlo más eficiente añadiendo un break si ya ha detectado que hay un número que no es primo.

```
def primo(n: list):
    cont = 0
    for num in n:
        for i in range(2,num):
            if num%i == 0:
                cont += 1
                break
    
    if cont > 0:
        print('Alguno no es primo')
    else:
        print('Todos son primos')
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho tu respuesta, es justamente el problema que quería solucionar. Lo tomo en cuenta para seguir aprendiendo Python. Gracias.

Comment: Es un placer 